# Django Filter on most common occurrence in many to many field

Tags: python, django

I would like to filter/exclude my query-set based on the most common occurrence (mode) of my many to many field which is a charfield:

For example in my example below I would like to filter among the classes that contain classrooms with students where "David" is the most common name in the class. (Django version 1.9.2)

```
#models.py
class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Class(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    students = models.ManyToManyField(Student)

#views.py
Class.objects.filter(students__mode = 'David')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need django aggregations [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/aggregation/)

your query will be something like this (I'm not sure it's the exact query or not but using the docs and this sample you will get the idea how it works)

```
Class.objects.filter(
    students__name="David"
).annotate(
    david_count=Count('students')
).order_by(
    'david_count'
)
```

Comment: Should "devid_count" be "david_count"?

Comment: @David yes, It's typo there :-))